# How to manually register a user into mongoDB Collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to register a user with an admin right on my mongodb admin user collection.

This is my admin model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const adminUserSchema = new Schema({
    userType: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
},
{
    timestamps: true
}
);

export const adminUser = mongoose.model('adminUser', adminUserSchema);
```

Below is how I entered the admin collection:

```
{
  userType
"adminUser"
email
"admin@mail.com"
password
"Password"
}
```

I got an error that the data cant be entered as it contains error.
The screenshort of the error:
[image]

Below is how I entered the admin collection:

```
{
  userType
"adminUser"
email
"admin@mail.com"
password
"Password"
}
```

I got an error that the data cant be entered as it contains error.
The screenshort of the error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your background filter, you need to separate values into `key:value` pair like JSON

```
{
  userType: "adminUser"
  email: "admin@mail.com"
  password: "Password"
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work bro.